# Launch ASP.NET Core API from windows service

Tags: asp.net, .net, api, asp.net-core, controller

I have a small API created from a ASP.NET core Api template in visual studio 22 that targets .NET6.
For testing\debuging I'm launching the API using console application and everything works.
But for production I need this API to be started from a windows service and I have no idea how to make it.

I could simply put the .exe in same folder as the service and call it, but far as I now if no user logged in the console app won't start.
So the idea is to pack the API together with all services and start it when windows service starts.

I've made a small test by creating a static class name "Test.cs" with a method named "Start" and copy all the code from "Program.cs" and call the "Start" method from a test application.
The API starts and stays listening to the endpoints but for some reason doesn't map the controllers from project controllers folder.

[all OK when starting API from default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjQO4.png)

[controllers not mapped when start API from static method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrRIW.jpg)

program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


//to avoid json serialize camel casing


builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(opts => 
{ 
    opts.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
    opts.JsonSerializerOptions.NumberHandling = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonNumberHandling.AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals; //para aceitar NAN, infinitos etc no json
});
//////////


//Nedeed
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
});



var app = builder.Build();


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

//app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

test.cs

```
namespace ProjectX.Api
{
    public static class Test
    {

        public static void Start()
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();

            // Add services to the container.

            builder.Services.AddControllers();
            // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


            //to avoid json serialize camel casing


            builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(opts =>
            {
                opts.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
                opts.JsonSerializerOptions.NumberHandling = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonNumberHandling.AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals; //para aceitar NAN, infinitos etc no json
            });
            //////////


            //Nedeed
            builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
            });



            var app = builder.Build();



            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            //app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllers();


            app.Run();

        }


    }
}
```

tester app

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ProjectX.Tester
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                ProjectX.Api.Test.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex )
            {


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the `exe` file of Web Api directly in `Start()`:

```
public static void Start()
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.FileName = "Your Path\\ProjectName.exe";
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    startInfo.Arguments = "";
    try
    {
        using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            exeProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        //Log error.
    }
}
```

Then you can successfully call the API in the project:
[image]

If you want to apply Swagger, please add the following code in the production environment in `Program.cs`:

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
```

Result:
[image]

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this will work if no user logged in ? Let's say I have this running on a server and server restarts so my windows service also restarts, this process will run before any user log in ?                              Thanks

Comment: If you start your API project through a windows service, when your windows service restarts, you should be able to run the API's exe file successfully. But if your authentication is in the API project, that might fail because it's not possible to cross user authentication to access it.

Comment: I will make a test comming week  and see how its going ! Big thanks